# Passing parameter to a custom validation attribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I wanna create a custom validation attribute to validate `StartTime` and `EndTime` which refer from the text inputs.

I have tried:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool GoldTime { get; set; }

    [TimeValidation(@"^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$", GoldTime, ErrorMessage = "Start time is invalid.")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    [TimeValidation(@"^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$", GoldTime, ErrorMessage = "End time is invalid.")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Validation attribute:

```
public class TimeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _pattern;
    private readonly bool _useGoldTime;

    public TimeValidationAttribute(string pattern, bool useGoldTime)
    {
        _pattern = pattern;
        _useGoldTime = useGoldTime;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_useGoldTime)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(_pattern);

            if (!regex.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'MyModel.GoldTime'

Then, I've tried again by changing `GoldTime` (in the model) to `true`, the error message would disappear.

So, my question is: How can I pass the parameter `GoldTime` to the attribute constructor? I need to use the `GoldTime` as a key to enable validating the value of `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

Thank you!

Comment: Your parameter needs to be the name of the other property, not the actual value of the other property (and in your method you use reflection to get the value of the other property). I recommend reading [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) to understand how to create a custom validation attribute

Comment: As a side note, using `string` for a property which appears to be either a date or a time is not appropriate. And your regex allows `90:80` which I assume is also not valid

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the link and the note. I'm reading the doc.

Comment: What is it that your actually wanting to validate here? If the values are supposed to be times as your property names suggest, then your properties should be `TimeSpan`, but its not clear what `GoldTime` means

Comment: @StephenMuecke I use `GoldTime` as a key to make sure that user needs to use the gold time with `StartTime` and `EndTime`. Otherwise, `StartTime` and `EndTime` would be ignore (no need to update to the database).

Comment: @StephenMuecke If `GoldTime` returns `true`, `StartTime` and `EndTime` doesn't allow null or empty, otherwise, it allows but it requires matching with the regex.

Comment: Then what you want is a `[RequiredIf]` attribute. You could use the one from  [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) or write your own (refer [this example](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation/blob/master/scripts/sandtrap-unobtrusive-validation-v2.0.js))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152755/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-yeah).

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining about using a model property within the attribute definition.  Instead, within your custom attribute, you can use properties on the ValidationContext class to get the underlying model, I think via `validationContext.ObjectInstance`.

Obviously, you don't want to hard-code the type of model but you could use reflection:

```
bool goldTime;
var prop = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("GoldTime");
if (prop != null)
   goldTime = (bool)prop.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
```

Or, define an interface for the model:

```
public interface ITimeModel
{
   bool GoldTime { get; set; }
}
```

And look for that:

```
bool goldTime;
if (validationContext.ObjectInstance is ITimeModel)
  goldTime = ((ITimeModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance).GoldTime;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try.